# NameError: name 'members' is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, api

I am trying to access a public API. The error is NameError: name 'members' is not defined. I want to be able to access the 'uuid' as shown below my code. I have been at this for a while and I can't quite figure out what is wrong.

```
import requests
import json

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
# Getting guild information

guildUuids = (data["guild"]["members"])

for guild in data["guild"]:
    print(members['uuid'])
```

```
{

> "success": true,
> "guild": {
> > "_id": "5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43",
> > "name": "Knowledgeable",
> > "name_lower": "knowledgeable",
> > "coins": 0,
> > "coinsEver": 0,
> > "created": 1595298905072,
> > "members": [
> > > {
> > > > "uuid": "0baac74f903143e49d24015d8bc3a733",
> > > > "rank": "Skilled",
> > > > "joined": 1597007947865,
> > > > "questParticipation": 157,
> > > > "expHistory": {
> > > > > "2020-11-17": 0,
> > > > > "2020-11-16": 0,
> > > > > "2020-11-15": 81622,
> > > > > "2020-11-14": 122670,
> > > > > "2020-11-13": 113692,
> > > > > "2020-11-12": 148,
> > > > > "2020-11-11": 15650
> > > > }
> > > },
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no variable called `members` in your code. That's why you get this error message. I don't quite understand what is unclear to you about that.

Comment: I understand the error, but I am quite new to understanding much about json files. I now understand how I can fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined variables in your code and it is very messy. You should do something like this:

```
import requests
import json

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
# Getting guild information

for guild in data["guild"]["members"]:
    print(guild["uuid"])
```

Ouptut:

```
0baac74f903143e49d24015d8bc3a733
031c3178bfd04099b34301185d1182f3
c1558354fe2a48dabfa47cbce58cbe14
b4a5d02f35064dda9d84b58b238d0b62
69eda71c66ab4020ac394ba71dc84277
6cf3bb8096d048aca54ae52b987b0359
be3230d820b74a44a34854936499bb23
24002c0cce6343f2b0a8c090719da59d
2dcecd25388c46cf844022838415c0fd
ac8f62b779624750ad287320f2505cea
ba0e524403bf42a5a37da6ae47cc3b13
77dbb04c9f8d45b2bb87465f0f091b81
eabd1e2bb33948d0959fae8f9752d41c
91518e98445a46aca9b091341f2441f2
eff2569063624eadb8d19daecd8f8e21
6a0c5479ad7b4cb396867e62a4eb5865
3599ecd42ff14e698d83bb052d5e4e27...
```

Answer (score 1):

With `print(members['uuid'])`, you're telling python to call the function `members` on the array `['uuid']`. You probably meant to access the `members` field in `data["guild"]`. In that case you'd have to do this:

```
for member in guildUuids:
    print(member['uuid'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the member property of the guild. However, your code just says to access a variable named members. There is no such variable so you're getting that error.

```
import requests
import json

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
# Getting guild information

for member in data["guild"]["members"]:
    print(member['uuid'])
```